# jQuery click event not working when mouse moves from one div to another with button held down

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've made a page that uses jQuery to allow you to place `<div>`s on the page based on your mouse coordinates when you click.

[**The page**](http://acorn.host22.com/tiles.html)

And here's the javascript:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $("#canvas").click(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    $(document.createElement('div')).css({'left':x + 'px', 'top':y + 'px'}).addClass('tile').appendTo('#canvas');
    });
});
```

I've found that if you mousedown in the `div#canvas` and mouseup with your pointer over a placed `<div>` (or vice versa) then a new `<div>` doesn't get placed. Why is this?

**EDIT:**

Ok, so the problem is that the mouse-up and mouse-down events are registering in different elements so it doesn't make a click event. So how do I get my mouse-up part of the click ignore the `div.tile` elements (the pink rectangles) and register in the `div#canvas` element to create the click event?

Comment: There's mousedown, mouseup and click. They're all different.

Comment: Your jQuery code is needlessly verbose; see my answer for a shorter equivalent.

Comment: That sounds like a drag to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle `mouseup` instead of `click`.

**EDIT**: To ensure that the corresponding `mousedown` happened inside `#canvas`, yuo can handle it and check, like this:

```
var mousedownInCanvas = false;

$(document).mouseup(function() { mousedownInCanvas = false });

$('#canvas').mousedown(function() {
    mousedownInCanvas = true;
}).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (!mousedownInCanvas) return;

    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    $('<div class="tile"></div>').css({ left: x, top: y }).appendTo('#canvas');
});
```

Comment: But what if I only want a `div.tile` to be placed if the user moused down within `div#canvas`?

Comment: You can handle mousedown and check.

Comment: I'm not having any luck with the method you posted. Any idea why no `<div>` s are getting placed? http://acorn.host22.com/tiles2.html

Comment: @Acorn: We misspelled the classname. (`title` vs `tile`)  If you paste `javascript:void($('.title').addClass('tile'))` into the address bar, a tile will appear in every place that you clicked.

Answer (score 2):

I believe its not a click unless the mouseup and mouse down occur on the same element.

From the jQuery docs:

> The click event is sent to an element
>   when the mouse pointer is over the
>   element, and the mouse button is
>   pressed and released. Any HTML element
>   can receive this event.

More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

A click consists of a mouse-down and a mouse-up event.  Since your mouse-down originated in another div, the secondary div will not register a click.

Comment: Is there any way I can make my mouse-up event register in the `div#canvas` even if there is a `div.tile` in the way?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from DannyLane and SLaks are very useful. It took me forever to find the cause of my bug. I've got a modal popup window (AjaxControlToolkit, ModalPopupExtender, with Bootstrap styling) with a cancel button. However, it looked like the user had to click twice to dismiss the popup. Looking at the source, all events are hooked up properly.

It turns out that as described in the jQuery docs, my mouse-down event was on the cancel button element, but an OnBlur event elsewhere caused the layout to shift (to display a validation error), and it turns out the mouse-up event ends up on a different element to what it started on. Therefore, the click event doesn't get fired. See the picture for a graphic explanation.

[image: Popup showing the steps to invalidate my click event]
My fix, since I've got too many popups to deal with them one by one is to use the mousedown event.

I bind all my "not primary buttons inside my modal", ie, my cancel buttons ('.modal-content .modal-footer a:not(.btn-primary)'.

When mousedown is fired, I get the closest parent that represent my popup DIV element (they all are '.modal-content.modalPopup') for me.

And then I try to find the Ajax COMPONENT which represent the popup. This is not the DIV, it it the 
ModalPopupExtender normally represented by it BehaviorId, but since I don't have that BehaviorId, I use the only way I found to get it by looping through all components.

I can then call the Ajax Hide() method, not the same as jQuery hide().

The bidding:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
    var cancel = jQuery('.modal-content .modal-footer a:not(.btn-primary)');
    cancel.mousedown(function () {
        var popup = jQuery(this).closest('.modal-content.modalPopup')[0];
        if (popup) HidePopupByPopupDiv(popup.id);
    });
    //cancel.css('background-color', 'red'); //debug to see my cancel buttons hooked up
});
```

and the hiding method:

```
function HidePopupByPopupDiv(popupPanelDivId) {
    var c = Sys.Application.getComponents();
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if (c[i].get_PopupControlID && c[i].get_PopupControlID() == popupPanelDivId)
            c[i].hide();
    }
}
```